# Using CRL parameter in DocuSign Button

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, docusignapi

I have a custom button that I am creating.  Everything in the button is functioning perfectly except for the recipient mapping.  Whenever I try to create an envelope, it only pulls in the primary contact as the carbon copy but it doesn't pull in Signer 1.  Is there something that I am missing?

```
//Custom Recipient List
var CRL='Email~{!Opportunity.AP_Contact_Email__c};FirstName~{!Opportunity.AP_Contact_First_Name__c};LastName~{!Opportunity.AP_Contact_Last_Name__c};Role~A;RoutingOrder~1;Email~' + primaryContact.Email + ';FirstName~' + primaryContact.FirstName + ';LastName~' + primaryContact.LastName + ';Role~B,RoutingOrder~2';

//Custom Contact Role Map
var CCRM='A~Signer 1;B~Carbon Copy';

//Custom Contact Type Map
var CCTM='A~Signer;B~Carbon Copy';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the comma around to separate the two recipients.  Right now the second recipient has only a RoutingOrder.  (Recipients are comma-delimited while recipient fields are semi-colon delimited.)

E.g.:

```
//Custom Recipient List
var CRL='Email~{!Opportunity.AP_Contact_Email__c};FirstName~{!Opportunity.AP_Contact_First_Name__c};LastName~{!Opportunity.AP_Contact_Last_Name__c};Role~A;RoutingOrder~1,Email~' + primaryContact.Email + ';FirstName~' + primaryContact.FirstName + ';LastName~' + primaryContact.LastName + ';Role~B;RoutingOrder~2';

//Custom Contact Role Map
var CCRM='A~Signer 1;B~Carbon Copy';

//Custom Contact Type Map
var CCTM='A~Signer;B~Carbon Copy';
```

Cheers,
Jeff

Comment: I do have another question.  I am able to get this to work in my dev environment but as soon as I paste this code into my client's environment he is getting an "unexpected identifier error".  My code, one I change the comma, is correct, right?  The other thing I can think that would break this is that he's adding commas, apostrophes, etc. into the salesforce fields.   To fix that, all I would have to do is put {!JSENCODE(Opportunity.AP_Contact_First_Name__c) to fix it, right?